# Volume of an arbitrary shell

Tags: multiple-integral

Assume I have a solid $f_1(x,y,z) = 0$ and I have another solid $f_2(x,y,z) = 0$ that fits entirely within $f_1$.  If I wanted to compute the volume of the shell $V = f_1 - f_2$ I just need to do a triple iterated integral and be done with it.  However, I would like to know, if $f_2$ and $f_1$ describe the same shape, but $f_2$ is just scaled, is there a simpler way of computing the volume?

For instance, if $f_2$ is defined such that I know the thickness of the shell is 0.5 everywhere, is there a simplification I can use to get the amount of material in the shell itself?

Comment: "Just scaled" how?

Comment: In the sense that its outer shell is parallel to the inner shell of $f_1$.  I have just realized that determining a curve parallel to another is difficult, so I suspect that this question isn't quite rigorous enough to be answered...

Comment: I figure you mean something like $f_2(cx) = c^\alpha f_1(x)$ for some $\alpha$? My understanding of "shells" is that the walls will always be concentric cylinders.

Comment: Definitely not, because the shape is still arbitrary so there isn't a more general way to find the volume than integration. Were they simple shapes like ellipsoids/cones/ paraboloids/etc it would of course be simpler